# Masking cards usgins jolt

Tags: json, jolt

How can I iterate through list and replace some elements in it? I have this input

```json
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientId": "166734",
      "info": {
        "cards": [
          "378282246310005",
          "371449635398431"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want mask cards like this **`"cards" : [ "3782*****0005", "3714*****8431" ]`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformations to convert the cards array to indexed and 0,1,** labeled objects in order to prepare for **modify** transformation spec in which ***substring*** and ***concat*** functions are used such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": {
                "@": "&5[#5].&3.&2.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": {
                "p1": "=substring(@(1,&1),0,4)",
                "p2": "=substring(@(1,&1),11,15)",
                "cs": "=concat(@(1,p1),'********',@(1,p2))"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "clients": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "info": {
            "cards": {
              "*": {
                "cs": "&5[#5].&3.&2[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```